# Suppress about:blank in Print Output of WinForms WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

I'm updating a WinForms application that uses System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser to output some HTML content generated by the program.  The solution works fine, except that `about:blank` is printed in the footer of each page.

Is it possible to suppress that output?  Alternatively, is there a straightforward alternative  for printing HTML from WinForms that does not have that issue?

The client does not want to assume the presence of any third-party software such as Excel or even a PDF reader.

Answer (score 5):

```
public void ClearBrowserPrintHeaderAndFooter()
{
    string path = "Software\\\\Microsoft\\\\Internet Explorer\\\\PageSetup";
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true);
    if (key == null) {
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path, true);
    }
    key.SetValue("header", "");
    key.SetValue("footer", "");
    key.Close();
}
```

Silly but it's the way.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7, however it is good practice to save the registry value via key.GetValue before the print, and to restore the original value once the print is complete. Otherwise, the setting will remain cleared on that user's machine for subsequent IE prints.