# Printing an HTML document

Tags: c#, html, printing, webbrowser-control, printing-web-page

I'm printing an HTML document successfully with the following code:

```
using (WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser())
{
    webBrowser.DocumentText = text;
    while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        Application.DoEvents();

    InternetExplorer internetExplorer = (InternetExplorer)webBrowser.ActiveXInstance;
    internetExplorer.PrintTemplateTeardown += InternetExplorer_PrintTemplateTeardown;
    internetExplorer.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER);

    while (!documentPrinted)
        Application.DoEvents();

    internetExplorer.PrintTemplateTeardown -= InternetExplorer_PrintTemplateTeardown;
}
```

Two problems:

1. The printed paper has an header (`page 1 of 1`) and a footer (`about:blank` and `date`). How can I print without them?
2. The printed paper is much longer than the actual HTML page content. How can I stop the printing when the content ends?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19172580/1768303

Comment: Thanks, the thread is informative but I cannot change the web page I am printing. Is there a way to clear those header and footer without altering the page?

Comment: Yes, there's a link at that thread to `IDM_PRINT` which allows to set custom header/footer (including an empty one).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8851626/945456

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution without using a custom print template.
This code clears the header and footer:

```
    const string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup";

    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("footer", string.Empty);
            key.SetValue("header", string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

In order to cut the paper in the thermal printer when the browser's content ends, I've added the `PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION` parameter to this line:

```
internetExplorer.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, Win32.PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION);
```

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time. Thank you.