# Remove header and footer when printing from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, print-preview, page-setup

I have a C# application that use MySql database. I built a report using HTML.

I fill string attribute with tags and send the content to a WebBrowser control in a new form.

The report appear correctly, but when I call print preview dialog,

```
webBrowser1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
```

the header and footer appear in the report with values:

- In header: # of pages.
- In footer: Date and "about:blank".

This is a screenshot for the issue:

[image]

How could I remove the header and footer?

Comment: These are settings on the print dialog as far as I can remember, not sure you can turn them off via your code.

Comment: I checked it, nothing their related to them.

Comment: what browser are you using? Internet Explorer?

Comment: i'm not using browser!, i added WebBrowser object to a form.

Comment: See my new answer, it will most likely be internet explorer settings internally if its a microsoft webbrowser control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress about:blank in Print Output of WinForms WebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851626/suppress-aboutblank-in-print-output-of-winforms-webbrowser). I've flagged it just to connect these similar questions together so it's easier to find similar situations/solutions :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you may have to change registry settings before printing, then change them back again:

*How To Programmatically Change Printer Settings for Internet Explorer and WebBrowser Control by Using Visual C# .NET*

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313723

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
//...............................

public  void IESetupFooter()
{

    string strKey  =  "Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\PageSetup";
    bool bolWritable = true;
    string strName = "footer";
        object oValue = "Test Footer";
    RegistryKey oKey  = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(strKey,bolWritable);
    Console.Write (strKey);
    oKey.SetValue(strName,oValue);
    oKey.Close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thaaat's it's :D .. Thanks Mr. Wraith

Comment: srry but do u have any idea about PrintPreview size (Width & hight) ?

Comment: i have had a look at the registry key and there is 2 attributes for header and footer. I cant work out exactly what the data value means, but im sure if you change the settings in the print dialog and look at the key again that is the value you need to set them to. I have just turned mine off, and it has cleared both variables so I think you need to set them to blank. Ill add a picture.

Comment: I found on my Win11 machine that the header/footer keys were missing by default. In that case it defaults to header "Page X of X" and footer "[URL]  [DATE]". When I added in blank header/footer keys the header and footer went away.